# Log Rotation MySQL Windows Batch

Tags: mysql, winforms, batch-file

I was asked to turn on log rotation for slow logs in mysql installed on a windows machine.
Since my experience with mysql is almpust equal to 0 i was wondering if you guys can help. I'm trying to create a batch that will be executed in task scheduler every week. So I would like to know if i can rotate the log without restarting the mysql service.

I do know that i shall execute:
    SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
    SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';
rename the logs
    SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
    SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';

Now how to execute this in a batch?

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -u "..." -p "..." -e "SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';" db_name
mysql -u "..." -p "..." -e "SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';" db_name
ren log_file log_file_old
mysql -u "..." -p "..." -e "SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';" db_name
mysql -u "..." -p "..." -e "SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';" db_name
```

Or put statements in `.sql` files and

```
mysql -u "..." -p "..." db_name < disable_logging.sql
ren log_file log_file_old
mysql -u "..." -p "..." db_name < enable_logging.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, but iti didn't work, it seems that something is wrong. Typing mysql.exe -u "root" -p "pass"  NameOfDb doesn't seem to work, i would aspect to return a problem with the user or pass but no it is like it is ignoring all the arguments, it returns all the parametres of mysql like i would simpy type mysql.exe

Comment: Try to use `--user`, `--password`, `--database`, `--execute` options. Also check [option files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I have executed the next command and it demanded me the password and it seems that the password set in the command is ignored and it is taken as the db name : "c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" --user root --password testpass --database testdb --execute "SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';" || Enter password: ******* || ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'testpass'

Comment: Try `mysql --user=root --password=testpass --execute="SET SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';"`.

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user   root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Is this answer an alternative to using `FLUSH LOGS`, or do I still need to run `FLUSH LOGS`.  See my [serverfault question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/915486/how-to-rotate-mysql-query-logs-on-windows)

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative. And this method works on any platform.